# How to disable acronyms use in Table of content?

Tags: table-of-contents, acronyms

Facts:

- In my latex document I generate a Table of content (TOC) that is inserted
  at the beginning of the document.
- The current TOC includes both the description of acronym and short form of it: acronym (ACR)

Aim:

- I would like to only show the short form in the TOC. As showing the description as well takes too much space.

Problem:

- I do not know how to tell that to the generator, as the line i use to automatically generate the TOC is: `\tableofcontents`

If any one knows how to do this, i'd be very thankful for the hint.
Thank you

Comment: The first hint is for you to provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can process that shows your problem.

Comment: If you use the package glossaries for your abbreviations, you should follow the advice not to put \gls{} commands into \section{}. Only an idea, because of missing MWE.